# Using Angular service and not changing variable from function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using an angular service to get a list of inventory items, check to see if an item is in that list, and remove it. However, I don't want to change the service variable itself, just the temporary value I create. Here is my code:

```
var inventoryItems = InventoryService.all();
console.log("inventorya: ", InventoryService.all());
inventoryItems.splice($index, 1);
console.log("inventoryb: ", InventoryService.all());
```

I expect InventoryService.all() to return the **same** value at all times, but it mutates the value returned. I've tried:

```
var inventoryItems = new Object(InventoryService.all());
```

but that doesn't appear to work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone the array with [angular.copy()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy). e.g.

```
var inventoryItems = angular.copy(InventoryService.all());
```

Or better yet you could copy the array from inside your `InventoryService` so you don't have to think about it when you are using it

Comment: As a follow up, how would I get it so that anything calling Inventory.all would get updated after I update inventory  (on purpose using another function like Inventory.add)

Comment: You can't do that. You can either have everything that calls `Inventory.all()` share the same instance of the array (the way you had it originally) or you can have everything have it's own instance (the `angular.copy()` way).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `InventoryService.all()` returns an array. If you splice the array you alter the contents of the array. Since it's a reference to an array all references reflect those changes. Sounds like what you want is to return a copy of the array.

You can do that by calling Array.slice(). Like so:

```
var inventoryItems = InventoryService.all().slice();
```

Answer (score 0):

If InventoryService.all() returns an Object then you are assigning the Object reference to inventoryItems. You have to create a new Object or clone it.

Here's a fiddle for the test:
http://jsfiddle.net/ew5hgkpx/

```
var test1 = testFactory.getObj();
console.log(test1); // returns [1,2]
//var test2 = testFactory.getObj().splice(0,1);
// test1 now return [2]

var test3 = Object.create(testFactory.getObj()).splice(0,1);
// test1 still returns [1,2]
```